# Distributing python package using setup tools

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, python-packaging

I have a python project that has a project structure with sibling imports (importing packages from same level in directory structure). I was able to get this working using setup tools.

I have a setup.py with the following in the top level of my package:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='myproject', version='1.0',
      packages=find_packages(), python_requires='>=3.4')
```

I then did a `pip3 install -e .` which allowed me to import sibling modules by prefixing the import statements with `myproject.`. This works fine, but when i add this code to version control and clone the project somewhere else, i run into the same issues with sibling imports. Is there a way to avoid running this command to install my top level package via pip every time someone clones this repo? I have tried doing this all in a virtualenv and activating it in the location that clones the repo, and also putting the `.egg-info` directory in version control, to no avail. How can i distribute this package so if this repo is cloned others can run the code?

I am relatively new to python so i apologize in advance if I'm missing something obvious. If there are better suggestions for distributing this code I am open to learning as well. Thanks in advance!

Edit: (follow up to comments)
My project structure(simplified) is something like (below), where modules in a and b will need to import eachother. I was able to accomplish this as mentioned above, but my use case will require me to deploy this code and run a script on a schedule(suppose a.py). If i have a pipeline deploy this code, it should be able to run without having to manually run "pip install ." While i used setup tools to resolve my issue with sibling imports, I realize this may not be the right approach, and am open to suggestions. Thanks in advance!

```
.
├── project
│   ├── a
│   │   ├── a.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── b
│   │   ├── b.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── __init__.py
```

Comment: Why do you _want_ people to clone your source repo and use your package directly out of the source tree instead of installing it? That's usually not a good idea. When it _is_ the right idea, you have to design everything differently, and `setuptools` can't help (unless you want people to build `--inplace` to shuffle the files around within the source tree, but that's usually not helpful), because `setuptools` is about installing things.

Comment: Maybe setup tools isn't the correct approach then, i stumbled upon it when trying to resolve an issue with sibling imports. What i'm looking for is to deploy my code (via some deployment pipeline) to different hadoop cluster nodes and run it there. If i don't know where it's going to run, i need some way of being able to package the code automatically. I am trying to clone the  repo on another cluster and run as is to verify this will work

Comment: Looks like the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Why don't you rather share a [mcve] of your project structure and imports, along with import error you get? Maybe you won't need to package the code with `setuptools` after all.

Comment: @hoefling you are right, I apologize. I have updated the question with my use case and a minimal example of my project structure.

Comment: I would remove `__init__.py` from the `project` dir (assuming it is the root dir in Git), then after cloning the repo on the target machine, add the `project` dir to path: `export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/project`.

Comment: This worked for me thank you! If you make it an answer i can select it as the best one. I had added a little shell script to export the pythonpath during deployment

Answer (score 0):

When you install using pip, it finds all the packages and install them relative to the parent package so you can import by prefixing with the project. So wherever you want to use, you will have to run the pip.

However if you would like to avoid running without going through pip, although may not be recommended, you can do the following assuming /app/home/packages is your current folder:

```
    import sys
    sys.path.append("/app/home/packages")
```

This command will search for all modules and then add to your path so that you don't need to run into sub module (sibling) imports. But when you are ready to distribute the package, you may want to remove this to make it as a clean distribution.